# google cloud speech api live stream Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I have implemented cloud speech API stream Recognition service . i am able to pass FLAC file and get output but it is not continuously recognizing and not giving out put still speaking. once my recording is done then only i am getting the response from cloud API. please advice me how to get continuous recognition from google speech API.
please help me

Answer (score 0):

Need to implement StreamingRecognizeRequest and google provide sample app to stream on live.

FLAC file not recommended for live streaming instead set it as LINEAR type

Comment: thanks for the reply. i will try as you adviced can you please post me the link of sample app